# Too many parameters in bat files

Tags: batch-file, cmd

```
@echo off

md C:\Users\%username%\Documents\"Backuped Minecraft Mods"

echo C:\Users\%username%\Documents\Backuped Minecraft Mods\Backups > C:\Users\%username%\Documents\"Backuped Minecraft Mods"\path.txt

set /p mpath=<"C:\Users\%username%\Documents\Backuped Minecraft Mods\path.txt"
echo %mpath%
tree /f %mpath%
pause
```

This is a part of bat file which I am making,
but I there is a problem in command `"tree /f %mpath%"`, I think.
When I run this, there is a error massage which says-

```
매개 변수가 너무 많습니다 - Minecraft
```

`매개 변수가 너무 많습니다` is `"Too many parameters"` in English.
I used only ONE parameter in tree command so why "Too many parameters"?

Comment: Is the `<` in front of the set-command required? (`set /p mpath=<"C:\Users\%username%\Documents\Backuped Minecraft Mods\path.txt"`)

Comment: @zeropublix - Yes; it's used to get the first line from the file.

Comment: And on that note, what _is_ the first line of path.txt? If there are spaces anywhere in it, `tree` will think there are multiple parameters.

Comment: C:\Users\awide\Documents\Backuped Minecraft Mods\Backups

Comment: maybe "Backuped Minecraft Mods" this would be the problem!

Comment: `tree /f "%mpath%"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some example code for you.

```bat
Echo Off

Set "bpath=%UserProfile%\Documents\Backuped Minecraft Mods"
Set "mpath=%bpath%\Backups"
Set "tpath=%bpath%\path.txt"

If Not Exist "%bpath%\" MD "%bpath%"
(Echo=%mpath%)>"%tpath%"
Rem Set /P "mpath="<"%tpath%"
Tree /F "%mpath%"
Pause
```

I've `Rem`arked line `9` which isn't required in the provided context of your snippet.